# Solving with less time complexity in python

Tags: python, performance

**--Content from Hacker rank--**

Please click on below link for problem description

[click here to go to problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/box-operations)

Code:

```
#!/bin/python3

import sys
from math import floor

n,q = input().strip().split(' ')
n,q = [int(n),int(q)]
box = list(map(int, input().strip().split(' ')))
# your code goes here
opera=[]
h=0
while h<q:
    opera.append(list(map(int, input().strip().split(' '))))
    h+=1
for g in opera:
    if g[0]==1:
        for i in range(g[1],g[2]+1):
            box[i]+=g[3]
    elif g[0]==2:
        for i in range(g[1],g[2]+1):
            box[i]=floor(box[i]/g[3])
    elif g[0]==3:
        c=[];
        for i in range(g[1],g[2]+1):
            c.append(box[i])
        print(min(c))
    elif g[0]==4:
        c=[];
        for i in range(g[1],g[2]+1):
            c.append(box[i])
        print(sum(c))
```

Can somebody help me out with an approach that reduces time complexity..

Comment: The pasted problem text is unreadable because all of the variables are missing.  Please fix the missing portions of the problem text and link to the relevant HackerRank problem (I believe it is [this](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/world-codesprint-9/challenges/box-operations)) so others can provide help with your solution.

Comment: Tried to fix the remaining portions of the problem. But,couldn't make it readable.So,kept the link for problem description.